# How to make infinite viewpager with calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-viewpager

I need my viewpager to be date bound. For example, it starts from today and you can scroll the screens either to the left and go to yesterday, the day before yesterday, and so on. To the right, if you scroll, then move on to tomorrow and further and further. Depending on the date that is now on the screen and different content of my pager, the content should be strictly linked to the date. Something like a daily calendar. How to implement this? I've been racking my head for a couple of days.

Comment: Truly "infinite" is pointless, as the user is not going to swipe an infinite number of times, and you will run into programming problems as you get towards the maximum value for an integer. Set up a pager with a number of pages that the user isn't going to hit (e.g., 1 million days = ~2,740 years). The halfway position (e.g,. 500,000) maps to today, and you start in that position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sure, of course it's not infinite, because calendar is not infinite in java\kotlin. I just want to know how to implement the connection above calendar and viewpager.